# Optimal PCA is 0?

Tags: r, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am following this post (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-tune-hyperparameters-of-tsne-7c0596a18868) to reduce of data's dimension with PCA; however, the according optimal PCA is 0! (100% sure the code is correct!) What should i do with this?

my data consists 500 rows and 400 columns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The line `optPC<-head(which(pval>=0.05),1)-1`  is taking 1 off the index of the first p value to rise above 0.5 - in your case, that's 1 principal component. You can see from your plot that there isn't a value at 0 components. Have you looked at the plot of the explained variance? If your code is correct, then it seems likely to me that there will be one column explaining most of the variance in the rest of the data, or some combination of columns that can be reduced easily to a single dimension.